# KDE Plasma does not sleep

Tags: linux, power-management, kde, kde-plasma-5

When I put the KDE Plasma to sleep it turns off the monitor and I hear the fans and the HDs shutting down just to back up to speed and the monitor turn on again on the blackened lock screen. So it is turning things off but immediately turn on again. I'm using X11 not Wayland

```
# systemd-inhibit --list --mode=block | cat
WHO        UID  USER PID  COMM            WHAT                                                                       WHY                      MODE
PowerDevil 1000 cpn  4135 org_kde_powerde handle-power-key:handle-suspend-key:handle-hibernate-key:handle-lid-switch KDE handles power events block

1 inhibitors listed.
```

I use Nvidia card with the proprietary driver.

[image]

Comment: You can try making certain you're on the latest BIOS; it might help.